# Rolling cumulative product based on elseif condition

Tags: r, cumulative-sum

I am looking for a way of doing a rolling product in an ifelse statement that is based on an additional column?

My data looks like this

```
    A    B   C 
 1  1    1   
 2  3    1   
 3  5    0
 4  7    0
```

The excel formula equivalent would be

```
C3 = IF(B3=0,(1+A3/10)*C2,1)
```

I tried using

```
ifelse(B==0,cumprod(c(1,(A[-1]/10+1))),1)
```

I couldn't get it working for this case as it is always referring to just the data in column A.

I would expect the following results

```
    A    B   C 
 1  1    1   1
 2  3    1   1
 3  5    0   1.5
 4  7    0   2.55
```

thanks in advance

Comment: you wrote `elseif`

Comment: ...and presumably you mean `ifelse()`.

Comment: Can you share your data reproducibly (e.g., with `dput`)? Having unequal number of rows in each column means you don't have a data frame or matrix, so it would be nice to see what structure there is. Are they just vectors?

Comment: I had elseif in my code, the data looks like the example, column C is empty when I start, I just put the starting values in as they will get the 1 assigned in the ifelse without using the rolling product

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
df$C <- cumprod(with(df, ifelse(B==0, A/10+1, 1)))
```

Or using `Reduce`:

```
df$C <- Reduce('*', with(df, ifelse(B==0, A/10+1, 1)), accumulate = T)
```